# How accurately I can tell when to display dummy content during loading a page?

Tags: http, reactjs, dom, single-page-application

When I click on a button that takes me from a home screen to settings screen that needs a lot of data and calculation from the server...

In a React single page app, is it possible to display the settings screen with blank components exactly 250 ms after the button click (see image below)?

[image: Image A]

Or I can't display the dummy content exactly after 250 ms because there always will be some interval between the click and some event? - A time interval of indefinite length that depends on a connection and server speed when I cannot affect what's on the screen (see image below).

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  Are you saying that you can't figure out how to render something exactly 250ms after a click event or that you've tried something and it's not working? Please post some code for this component to help clarify

Comment: I am not trying to implement it right now rather trying to figure out what I can promise. Whether it's possible to implement the transition between one screen to another screen in a way that a dummy content appears exactly after 250 ms after clicking the button that takes me to the second screen.

Comment: Well... I suppose you can start a timer when you click the link.. then if 250ms has elapsed yet keep waiting.. otherwise show the dummy content. Not sure why you would want to do this though